# App uploaded to Itunes Connect for testflight testing doesn't show correct screen size when downloaded

Tags: ios, storyboard, testflight, size-classes

Got a little problem, I'm not sure if there's something I missed when I uploaded my application for testflight testing. What's happening was when I download my application from testflight(I'm using iphone6). The screen size of my application doesn't fit as of that iphone 6 size. It looks like it renders the iphone 5 screen. I'm using size classes. But when I run my application directly from xcode to my device the screen is rendered correctly.

Need your help guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test your application in release mode and check all default images which you have added

Comment: I was able to fix it yesterday and it was indeed with the default images. I was thinking to use launch images instead of the launch screen xib file. So I removed the xib file and use the images, instead my app didn't render correctly. I think that the phone detects size classes based on the launch screen for iOS8 devices. Thanks.